# Pyspark select from empty dataframe throws exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

the question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417344/analysisexception-is-thrown-when-the-dataframe-is-empty-no-such-struct-field) but it had no answer, I have a dataframe from which am selecting data if exists

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("file_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("result", ArrayType(StructType()), True),

])

df = rdd.toDF(schema=schema)

print((df.count(), len(df.columns))) # 0,2

df.cache()

df = df.withColumn('result', F.explode(df['result']))

get_doc_id = F.udf(lambda line: ntpath.basename(line).replace('_all.txt', ''), StringType())

df = df.filter(df.result.isNotNull()).select(F.lit(job_id).alias('job_id'),
                                             get_doc_id(df['file_name']).alias('doc_id'),
                                             df['result._2'].alias('line_content'),
                                             df['result._4'].alias('line1'),
                                             df['result._3'].alias('line2'))
```

the above throws error when the dataframe is **empty**

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'No such struct field _2 in ;
```

shouldn't it only executes if `result` column had data ? and how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark executes code lazily. So it won't check whether you have data in your filter condition. Your code fails in Analysis stage because you don't have a column named result._2 in your data. You are passing empty StructType in your schema for result column. You should update it to something like this:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("file_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("result", ArrayType(StructType([StructField("line_content",StringType(),True), StructField("line1",StringType(),True), StructField("line2",StringType(),True)])), True)
])


df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(),schema=schema)

df = df.withColumn('result', F.explode(df['result']))

get_doc_id = F.udf(lambda line: ntpath.basename(line).replace('_all.txt', ''), StringType())


df = df.filter(df.result.isNotNull()).select(F.lit('job_id').alias('job_id'),
                                             get_doc_id(df['file_name']).alias('doc_id'),
                                             df['result.line_content'].alias('line_content'),
                                             df['result.line1'].alias('line1'),
                                             df['result.line2'].alias('line2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that 'df' does not have '_2'. So it ends up throwing errors like:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'No such struct field _2 in ;
```

You can try checking if the column exists by

```
if not '_2' in result.columns:
    #Your code goes here
```

I would generally initialise the column with 0 or None if it does not exists like

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
if not '_2' in result.columns:
        result = result.withColumn('_2', lit(0))
```